# Why is my sended mail getting name in this formar?

Tags: php

Hi I have issue with using mail function in php.
I am getting email to my example@gmail.com but name of sender is something like : uid86787

Full email I will receive looks like this:

```
uid86787
Subject: Some subject
To: myEmail@gmail.com
---------------------------
Body of email
Name: exampleName (I entered in form)
Email: exampleEmail (I entered in form)
Message: exampleMessage (I entered in form)
From: myPage.eu
```

What I need is change name uid86787 to myPage.eu. How can I do that please?

```
<?php
   $errors = array();
   $errorMessage = '';

   if (!empty($_POST)) {
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $message = $_POST['message'];

       if (empty($name)) {
           $errors[] = 'Meno je prázdne';
       }

       if (strlen($name) < 3) {
           $errors[] = 'invalid name';
       }


       if (empty($email)) {
           $errors[] = 'Email is empty';
       } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           $errors[] = 'Email is invalid';
       }

       if (empty($message)) {
           $errors[] = 'Message is empty';
       }


       if (empty($errors)) {
           $toEmail = 'example@gmail.com';
           $emailSubject = 'Správa cez stránku page.example';
           $headers = serialize(array('From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email, 'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'));



           $bodyParagraphs = array("Name: {$name}", "Email: {$email}", "Message:", $message, "From: mypage.eu}");
           $body = join(PHP_EOL, $bodyParagraphs);

           if (mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)) {
              $errorMessage = "<p style='color: green;'>{Email sended}</p>";
           } else {
               $errorMessage = 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later';
           }
       } else {
           $allErrors = join('<br/>', $errors);
           $errorMessage = "<p style='color: red;'>{$allErrors}</p>";
       }
   }
  ?>
```

Edit:
Why I have headers in serialize()
Answer: Live server runs on older php I think and it throws me error:

```
mail() function required 4th parameter as string
```

Before serialize I had it like this

```
$headers = ['From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email, 'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'];
```

Comment: Why do you `serialize()` your headers?

Comment: bcs server runs on older php and it throws me error like this:

Comment: Error mail() function required 4th parameter as string

Comment: What version of PHP is that then? It must have been out of support for many years. Time to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Don't `serialize()` your headers. To make your headers a string, change

```
$headers = serialize(array('From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email, 'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'));
```

to

```
$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" . 
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" . 
'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
```

See the examples on the [PHP mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) manual.

Comment: after change to this email has not send

Comment: Has it not been sent or has it not arrived? Did you check your junk folder? Do you get any errors? White page?

Comment: no errors, no email received , no emails in junk, no white page

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = 'From: info@vrtaniestudni.eu';
```

This changed the name of sender.